# How to get time stamp based on date(getting timestamp for the time of that particular date )

Tags: java, timestamp

Please resolve my issue

i am getting time stamp for date 16-03-2015 23:05 
  and also for 17-03-2015 00:10

i am calling after() method on 16-03-2015 23:05 by passing 17-03-2015 00:10 timestamp as as parameter

my issue is timestamp is considering only only time

so in this case 
timmestamp of 23:05 this is greater than 00:10

but when we compare with dates 17-03-2015 00:10 earliar than 16-03-2015 23:05

I want to get timestamp based on date is there any way to find
please help

Comment: What do you want exactly? 17-03-2015 00:10 cannot be earlier than 16-03-2015 23:05 unless you use different calendars.

Comment: Must be a date conversion bug on your side. `new java.sql.Timestamp(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm").parse("....").getTime())`

Comment: Do you want to compare only the time parts of the dates ?

Answer (score 1):

What timestamp-class do you use? When I try to reproduce your case with java.sql.Timestamp, everything is working fine:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class TimestampProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        long now = c.getTimeInMillis();
        Timestamp t = new Timestamp(now);
        // add only 23 hours in order to have less hours at next day
        c.add(Calendar.HOUR, 23);
        long later = c.getTimeInMillis();
        Timestamp t2 = new Timestamp(later);
        System.out.println(t2);

        System.out.println(t.before(t2) ? "alright: <" + t + "> before <" + t2
                + ">" : "Bäm");

        Date d = new Date(now);
        Date d2 = new Date(later);

        System.out.println(d.before(d2) ? "alright: <" + d + "> before <" + d2
                + ">" : "Bäm");
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Timestamp comparison alright: <2015-03-10 12:01:47.061> before <2015-03-11 11:01:47.061>
Date comparison alright: <Tue Mar 10 12:01:47 CET 2015> before <Wed Mar 11 11:01:47 CET 2015>
```

Maybe you can add a code-snippet.